# Finding constant values in a nonlinear equation

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, parameter-estimation, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

$V_{oc} = A_0 + A_1z + \frac{A_2}{z} + A_3ln(z) + A_4ln(1-z)$

I have the above non-linear equation to describe my model. $V_{oc}$ is measurable so I know its value. I know how $z$ is propagated with time. I am trying to find $A_i$, for $i=0,1,2,3,4$ so that I can estimate $z$ values for corresponding $V_{oc}$ in real time. Is there any way to find constant $A_i$ values?

Comment: Notice that in general, there can be several values of $z$ that fulfill the equation. Try $A_0=A_1=2, A_2=A_4=1, A_3=4$ and if you want $V_{oc}=1$, there are three different solutions for $z$ ...

Comment: Hi Matti, thank you for reply. $z$ is bounded between 0 and 1. Is there anyway to find the optimum value of $z$. $z$ is propagated according to the following equation $z_{k} = z_{k-1} -\frac{Idt}{Q}$. $I, dt, Q$ are known as well. I used the Particle Filter to estimate $A_i$ values and $z$ but it failed I think there was an observability problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimum value of $z$"? Is it the smallest one or ... ? Perhaps an iterative approach could work.

Comment: sorry for the typo. I wanted to say that $z$ has a true value for each $V_{oc}$ value. I want to find the best estimation of $z$. For example, if $V_{oc}$ is 8.4, $z$ should be around 1. I'd like to find the best estimate of $z$.